# Raspberry pi zero isn't detected by pc over USB

Tags: usb, pi-zero

So I've been working on a school project for the past couple weeks, and I've programmed over usb to make it the process easier. Everything was working fine for a solid 2 weeks until the system crashed and now both my laptop and my desktop won't detect the raspberry pi on my device manager. It doesn't show up as a port, or a usb ethernet/rndis gadget. I've tried flashing a new image and modifying the files needed for the setup (config.txt, cmdline.txt and ssh) so that's not the problem. I also reinstalled all the drivers (port, universal serial bus controllers and network adapters). The raspberry pi still works fine, I connected it to a monitor with a mini hdmi cable and i've connected a mouse/keyboard so the usb and power port still work.
I've run out of ideas :(
And both my computers are running windows 10.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a)?

Comment: This is a dumb suggestion - but, you haven't started using the power port to connect to the PC's instead of the OTG port?

Comment: No I've always used the OTG port. For more info, the raspberry pi works fine on it's own with peripherals connected directly to it. And my computer detects the raspberry when it's connected without the sd card.